# Substitute only one part of a string using perl

Tags: perl

I have an array that have some symbols that I want to remove and even thought I find a solution, I will like to know if this is the right way because I'm afraid if I use it with array will remove the character that I might need on future arrays.

Here is an example item on my array:

```
$string1='22      |      logging monitor informational';
```

so I try the following:

```
$string1=~ s/\s{6}\|(?=\s{6})//;
```

So my output is:

```
22      logging monitor informational
```

Is the other way that best match "|". I just want to remove the pipe character.

Thanks in advance

Comment: "The right way" is a rather subjective term. Are you trying to remove 6 whitespace followed by a pipe character? If so, yes, that's the right way.

Comment: I want to remove just the pipe character.

Comment: Then you should use a lookbehind assertion `(?<=\s{6})`. Since you have a fixed length string, that's ok. You can also use `\K` to "keep" the stuff on the left.

Answer (score 1):

> "I want to remove just the pipe character."

OK, then do this:

```perl
$string1 =~ s/\|//;
```

This will remove the first pipe character in the string.  (You said in another comment that you don't want to remove any additional pipe characters.)  If that's not what you want, then I'd suggest telling us exactly *what* you do want.  We can't read minds, you know.

In the mean time, I'd also strongly recommend reading the [Perl regular expressions tutorial](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html).